# toggle react hooks button and content at the same time

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

New react developer here, looking for react(hooks) toggle which toggles two things at the same time. My question: when user clicks 'Click here to show second Div content', then the content should change to '  < div>
Second Div content< / p>
< / div>' and button should change to 'Click here to show first Div content', how to have this as toggle... here what i have done so far:
https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-menu-forked-f144r?file=/src/App.js:426-483

what kind of impovements are needed here ?

Comment: Have you read / tried my answer? Mind giving some feedback, the accepted answer needs improvement please don't copy it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it like this;

```
  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setOpenMenu(!openMenu);

    if(openMenu){
    setOpenMenu2("first");
       } else {
      setOpenMenu2('second')
    }

  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={toggleMenu}
      >{`Click here to show ${openMenu2} Div content`}</button>

      {openMenu ? (
        <div>
          <p>First Div content</p>
        </div>
      ) : <div><p> Second Div content </p> </div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: State is set `asynchronous`, you are checking the toggle value right after it is set which will most of the time get you in trouble. The initial toggle value is `true`, so when you first press the button it is set to `false` but the value changes to `first` which should not be the wanted behavior.

Comment: @axtck you're actually correct but oddly it worked on sandbox, I'll check it later

Comment: Yes it looks like it works, but the values are not correct, try logging them

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [openMenu, setOpenMenu] = useState("first");

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    if (openMenu === "first") {
      setOpenMenu("second");
    } else {
      setOpenMenu("first");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={toggleMenu}
      >{`Click here to swap content`}</button>

      {openMenu === "first" ? (
        <div>
          <p>First Div content</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>Second Div content</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You were doing the right thing, but instead of returning `null` when `openMenu` is false, you should render the other content.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [openMenu, setOpenMenu] = useState(true);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setOpenMenu(!openMenu);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {openMenu ? (
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={toggleMenu}
          >{`Click here to show second Div content`}</button>
          <p>First Div content</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={toggleMenu}
          >{`Click here to show first Div content`}</button>
          <p>second Div content</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```